# bokeh hover alpha and color

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like my glyphs to change to an alpha value of 1 when hovered over.  However, if I set `hover_fill_alpha=1`, the color for the glyphs changes to the default blue color on hover.  I'm using a `ColumnDataSource` to determine the `fill_color` for the glyphs, but unfortunately when I set `hover_fill_color` to the very same column it turns out to be the wrong color.  The proportion of hover colors overall seems to be correct, but the glyphs are being assigned the wrong `hover_fill_color`.

So my question is how do I either set `hover_fill_alpha=1` without changing `hover_fill_color`, or if that is inevitable then how do I set `hover_fill_color` to be the same as `fill_color`?

```
hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [
        ("val", "@values"),
        ("(x,y)", "($x{int}, $y{int})")
    ]
)

plot = figure(tools=[hover, "pan, wheel_zoom, save"],
              active_scroll="wheel_zoom", sizing_mode="scale_both")


plot.patches('xs', 'ys', source=source, view=cdsview, line_alpha=1, fill_alpha=.5,
             line_color="black", fill_color="fill_colors", hover_fill_alpha=1,
             hover_fill_color="fill_colors", hover_line_color="black")
```

I'm using Bokeh 0.13.0, but it happens in previous versions as well.

edit: I think that this might be a bug when using a view.  If I remove the view, the `hover_fill_color` seems correct.  I really need the view to work though.

Comment: Your example does not work. Can you add the necessary imports?

Comment: It's not a fully working example.  It requires data and a view. I don't keep up with bokeh anymore but this was 6 versions ago, so it might not even be valid.